# Twitter Bootstrap - Navigation center

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, center, navbar

I have the Twitter Bootstrap framework and the navigation is not centered.
Thats my code:

```
    <div id="subnav" align="center">
       <div class="container">
           <a href="index.php">Startseite</a>
           <a href="youdesk.php">YouDesk</a>
           <a href="help.php">Hilfe</a> 
           <a href="imprint.php">Impressum</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

How can I center the navigation?

Thanks for any help.

Sorry for my bad english - I'm from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
 .navbar .nav,
    .navbar .nav > li {
      float:none;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar-inner {
      text-align:center;
    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qDUH3/10/

Comment: Thank you.
My navbar is named "subnav", heres a screen of my navigation:
http://i.imgur.com/bNjoS.png

I add your code. But its only center text in the black navigation.

Comment: which navigation are you trying to center. the gray navigation bar is centered